# How to concatenate two B-Trees ((d,2d) trees) with another node x

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

Assuming 2 B-trees T1, T2 are given. Also a key 'x'. I know that the leaves of each tree have between 2d-1 to 4d-1 keys, and I know that all the keys in T1 are greater then x and all the keys in T2 are smaller the x. 
What I am trying to do is to create a single B-Tree out of this trees. After trying then naive approach to just insert all the keys in the smaller tree, I tried to do the following:

1. Check if height(T1) > height(T2) (let's assume it was found true. If it's false it's really symmetrical.
2. On T1, I am going all the way down-left to height(T2)+1 and insert x as the leftmost key in the leftmost node in this height.
3. I Insert T2 as the left son of x.

I know that inserting x isn't a problem as I might need to do a sequence of splits up back to the root. My problem with my solution is that T2 might have only 1 key in its root(or any number of keys smaller than d-1) which breaks the B-Tree rule for internal nodes.
Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: What would wrong with creating a new root node containing the key x, then assigning T2 to the left and T1 to the right?  Then, do some rebalancing to bring the tree into a better format?

Comment: I thought about this too... I couldn't find a way to balance it. Any suggestions on how?

Comment: I don't know myself, but I'll bet Google would be rife with hits on balancing trees in general, probably B-trees as well.  Your problem seems tractable to me given that the two trees are already sorted as subtrees.

Comment: You merge the root of the shorter tree into the appropriate node of the taller tree.  You will have to put the key 'x' between two segments.  Then, if the node is too big, split it in half using the normal b-tree procedure.